# 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' error in installing apackage using pip3

Tags: python, pip, httrack

When I tried to install `httrack` in Ubuntu 16.04 I was not able to get those packages:

```
pip3 install httrack-py


Collecting httrack-py
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/58/b8/9499cd45ffb4efefff06090f04111c6572e7947eb4485d3333edc9505ed0/httrack-py-0.6.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: httrack-py
  Running setup.py install for httrack-py ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-96j_4z55/httrack-py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-f9__5p13-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    copying httrack.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5
    running build_ext
    building 'httracklib' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-6tVwKN/python3.5-3.5.2=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/home/petri/downloads/httrack-source -I/home/petri/downloads/httrack-source/src -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python3.5 -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c src/httrack-py.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/httrack-py.o
    src/httrack-py.c:45:29: fatal error: httrack-library.h: No such file or directory
     #include "httrack-library.h"
                                 ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-96j_4z55/httrack-py/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-f9__5p13-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-96j_4z55/httrack-py/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: Did you read the second sentence in the installation instructions?

Comment: I tried that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the code:
    sudo apt-get update 
And if its not working 
Try to update repository in software centre.

Answer (score 1):

The pip log says:

```
#include "httrack-library.h"
```

A necessary library header is missing.

Try running `sudo apt install libhttrack-dev` and then pip install again.

Comment: Brother  can can you suggest a tool for data extraction from a website...